# One select, two tables and no join

Tags: sql, join

I stumble upon below sql-code (translated for sample purpose) :

```
SELECT m.username, c.companyname 
FROM member m , company c 
WHERE m.id = 5 AND c.id = 10;
```

Table members has `id` as PK. Company has `id` as PK. There is no relation between these two tables.
At first I didn't think this would work, but it did.

Result is one row with value for `username` and `companyname`.

Before I saw this solution I would have gone for 2 sql - one for `member` and one for `company`.

What is the possible danger with this SQL?

Comment: I don't see any danger.   Why do you think there would be?

Comment: I don't see exactly what kind of results you are trying to get.

Comment: Hence the question. I havn't come across this way to select before and at first it looked strange. Like there is a missing join here. But since it works perhaps it's something one can use. Gordons sample with "CROSS JOIN" is a better way to make it more clear.

Comment: I say go with your first thought and use two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SQL is equivalent to:

```
SELECT m.username, c.companyname
FROM member m CROSS JOIN company c
WHERE m.id = 5 AND c.id = 10;
```

The comma and the `cross join` produce a cartesian product.  The `where` clause is presumably choosing one row from each table.  I much prefer the `CROSS JOIN` method and have a simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Can you please tell me, is there any standard practice of not using commas in from clause?

Comment: @NamanGala . . . Explicit `join` syntax has been part of the SQL standard for over twenty years.  Explicit joins are a more powerful syntax and hence preferable.

Comment: Why do you say "cartesian" product? The result of a Cartesian product operation is set of ordered pairs, which is not the case here. Just say 'product' and we'll infer you mean relational product (all relational operators take relations as arguments and result in a relation).

Comment: Amazing that there still is something to learn - CROSS JOIN. Never used it. The only thing I have against it that it contains the word "JOIN" and in this case it's not a JOIN as in "connect together". Perhaps it's a JOIN as "bring together".

Comment: "Explicit joins are a more powerful syntax and hence preferable" - how does replacing a comma with the keywords `CROSS JOIN` generate more "power"?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can use columns in the first table in subsequent `on` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you select from more than one table without joining them you get all possible combinations as result. In this case due to pk on both sides, you have only on result.

Comment: Correct and I understand that. Gordons sample with "CROSS JOIN" is a better way to show it. But, is it good practice to select two separate records in one select?

Comment: Hard to say: Coded like this it is hard to read/understand as your question itself shows. And of course it's a little dangerous as you could get an unwanted cartesian product if you modify it. On the other hand in this case you have to fire only on select-statement to recieve your result from both tables.